# switch or tumbler words meaning in software design

Tags: c#, algorithm, architecture, switch-statement, non-english

I created boolean setting in C# when I enable of disable some code execution. For example

```
If(_setting.EnableImport)
{
   Import()
}
```

When I talk to people in my team I used phrase:

"I created switch to enable of disable import"

I get some critics about using word "switch" for this, as it seems so wrong english word for code like this.

I am very interesting to know opinion about when I can use word switch in discussion in software developers teams. And when I must not use it, to avoid confusion.

What is your professional opinion about it.

Comment: I believe this is also known as a `feature toggle`. The word `switch` already has other meanings from a programming point of view.

Comment: [Feature Switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_toggle), see it goes by many names: Feature Switch/Toggle/Flag .... @MattJones, it'd be helpful to know what `switch` meaning is!

Comment: @BassemAkl the meaning of `switch` in programming languages can be easily googled. An obvious case would be the `switch statement`.

Comment: @MattJones, thanks! I thought you meant something else, not the `switch statement`.

Comment: You should ask your critics what word *they* would prefer. *I* understood perfectly what you meant.

Comment: Word Toggle is describe what I am doing very well, but for some reason I never heard that word Toggle is used in Software engineering. It is sort of issue when I use english word "Switch" and it produce misunderstanding, like I am not talking about code I introduced.